# Converting ascii to hex in VIM

Tags: vim, hex, vi

I often need to convert some small part of text I'm editing in vim from hex to ascii and other way around. I know I can pipe the text though xxd to accomplish this but I would like automatize this in a way that I visually select some text and then use a shortcut to convert the selected text to hex/ascii.

For example if I select `123 Foo` I would like to convert this to `31323320466f6f`.
Is there a vim plugin that does this? Can I use some function to do this?

Comment: not answering the question, but putting the cursor over a character and pressing `ga` givs the doc, hex, oct representation of said character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a **mapping** which can do that for you:

```
vnoremap ; :<c-u>s/\%V./\=printf("%x",char2nr(submatch(0)))/g<cr><c-l>`<
```

You can change **`;`** to any combination you want.

**Edit:**

You can reverse that as stated in comments by @CyberMuz:

```
vnoremap u :<c-u>s/\%V\x\x/\=nr2char(printf("%d", "0x".submatch(0)))/g<cr><c-l>`<
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there a way to convert the other way? So from `313233` to `123`?

Comment: @CyberMuz I will check it. nice try ! (+1)

Comment: I have come up with this mapping, it seems to be working correctly:
`vnoremap u :<c-u>s/\%V[0-9a-fA-F]\{2\}/\=nr2char(printf("%d", "0x".submatch(0)))/g"<cr><c-l>`<`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function, you pass in a string, it prints (echo)  the hex for you:

```
function! ToHex(str) abort
    let s = ''
    for c in split(a:str, '\zs')
        let s .= printf("%x", char2nr(c))
    endfor
    echo s
endfunction
```

If you change the `echo s` line into `return s`, you will get the converted string.  You can make it a "one-liner" by `map()`. However I think a loop is more readable.

I think that passing the visual selected stuff to the function, and modify the text with returned string isn't a problem for you right?